# html dropdown menu reloads when selection attempted - assistance please

Tags: python, html, menu, dropdown, reload

I am trying to create a drop-down menu of a list of countries that I will eventually use twice to select two countries to extract data from Database and graph. Using html, jinja, python and flask

I can generate the list of countries from the SQL in python... I can generate the html template using jinja which creates the dropdown menu. So far so good.

BUT When I click on the dropdown the list appears briefly but then the list immediately reloads so cannot actually make a selection and move to results.html.

Assume stuck in a loop - possibly due to confusion with '/' and '/search' in the route ? or perhaps GET / POST issues? something in layout?

Also seems to be a blank line between countries which would be nice to avoid!

Very grateful for advice please see extract from search.html and extract from application.py can post more info

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search():
"""Choose country"""
if request.method == "POST":
    # Ensure  Country A was submitted
    if not request.form.get("ctrya"):
        return apology("must select a country for Country A", 403)
    else:
        return render_template("results.html")
else:
    ctry_list = []
    # creating drop down list for the webpage
    countries = db.execute("SELECT country  FROM indicators GROUP BY country")
    for ctry in countries:
        ctry_list.append(ctry["country"])

    return render_template("search.html", country_list = ctry_list)
```

and for the html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
Search
{% endblock %} 
{% block main %}
<form action="/" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" name="ctrya">
          <option disabled="" selected="" value="">Country A</option>
              {% for ctrya in country_list %}
                 <option value="{{ctrya["country"]}}">{{ctrya["country"]}}
                 </option>
                <option>{{ctrya}}</option>
              {% endfor %}
       </select>
    </div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Compare countries</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try `print(countries)` to make sure it is actually fetching data from DB?

Comment: Hi thanks, yes, tried that and definitely fetching data from DB and it populates the list, I can see that is all good but when I click the drop-down arrow it populates the list with the countries and then reloads to its starting state rather than allowing me to make a selection or fully explore the list. Even if i try to click very fast while list populating it won't have it. Any thoughts ideas?